How to Precache API Requests in React Vite App with PWA?
I build a react app with vite, and want to make it works offline. The only thing I struggle with is precaching API requests - I'd like to prefetch some of them right after app is downloaded, not just when user go to some pages and trigger these fetches. Right now my vite config looks like that:
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), TanStackRouterVite(), VitePWA(pwaOptions)]
})

and pwaOptions are:
const pwaOptions: Partial<VitePWAOptions> = {
  mode: "development",
  base: "/",
  includeAssets: ["vite.svg", "favicon.png"],
  manifest: {
    name: "PWA Router",
    short_name: "PWA Router",
    theme_color: "#ffffff",
    icons: [
      {
        src: "favicon.png", 
        sizes: "200x200",
        type: "image/png",
      },
    ],
  },
  workbox: {
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: ({ url: { pathname } }) => {
          console.log({ pathname });
          return pathname.startsWith("/api");
        },
        handler: "CacheFirst" as const,
        options: {
          cacheName: "api-cache",
          cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [0, 200],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  devOptions: {
    enabled: process.env.SW_DEV === "true",
    type: "module",
    navigateFallback: "index.html",
  },
};

I tried to add custom service-worker file with:
precacheAndRoute(["/api/my-ep"]);

and include it in vite config, but it doesn't work.
